# Spring Security Method Without Login Form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to just secure the method but not the end point( API) with @Secured. In the over ride method that extends `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` i will have way to call the some dependent service if the user is allowed depending the on input passed in @Secured Annotation.

for example

```
@Secured("abc")

public void secureMethod(){

system.out.println("You are allowed)

}
```

The interceptor (that extends `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`) method will check if the input to `@Secured` method has input as `abc` or something and then return access_denied to this method only. The input to method will be passed by calling service and can be injected at run time.

How i can do that w/o having login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully got your question, but to disable the form-login including login/logout screens you would do this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity  
public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
    {
     security.formLogin().disable();
    }
}
```

**Note:** As you are using GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration , you can try and nest this class INSIDE it.

So:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    // do whatever is needed here

    @Configuration
    public static class WebSecurityConfig extends 
         WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  // nesting
         @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
        {
         security.formLogin().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to extend GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration to use accessDecisionManager. When i extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter then i cannot use accessDecisionManager